# How to batch insert with quill dynamic queries?

Tags: cassandra, bulkinsert, batch-insert, quill.io

I'm trying to use Quill dynamic queries to perform batch insert

In non-dynamic api I would've used:

```
db.run(quote {
liftQuery(myCollection).foreach(data => querySchema[MyDBClass]("table").insert(data))
})
```

I've tried doing the same for dynamic query:

```
db.run({
liftQuery(myCollection).foreach(data => dynamicQuerySchema[MyDBClass](tableNameVar).insertValue(data))
})
```

But I get the following error:

> No implicits found for parameter unquote: DynamicInsert[MyDBClass] => A_

Am I using the API correctly? any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The work-around is:

```
val dynamicSchema = context.dynamicQuerySchema[MyDBClass](tableNameVar)

context.transaction {
      myCollection.foreach { p =>
        context.run(dynamicSchema.insertValue(p))
      }
    }
```

For cassandra use without transaction

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated

Comment: For cassandra its really doing batching ? seems like it just inserting it one by one

Comment: Cassandra does not support transactions. `context.transaction` is ignored.

Comment: @AndrzejJozwik Do you know how to do this with Cassandra? Or is it just not possible?

Comment: @Noah Try without `context.transaction`